# Child themed template-tags.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templatetags

The theme I use has an `inc/template-tags.php` file that I

need to override with a child template-tags.php

Adding the file into my child theme folder both inc/ folder based and root child theme folder does not seem to override the parent file.

Adding `include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php' );`
to my child `functions.php` result in WordPress white screen of death.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Found the answer with the help of the WP community.

Comment: answer was in using the following inside child functions.php
if( ! function_exists(twentyfourteen_post_nav) ) {
 function twentyfourteen_post_nav() {
DUMP MY EDITED CODE HERE
}}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

answer was in using the following inside child `functions.php`

`if( ! function_exists(twentyfourteen_post_nav) ) { function twentyfourteen_post_nav() { DUMP MY EDITED CODE HERE }}`