# override parent theme /inc/template-tags.php

Tags: parent-child

Similar to the issue from [webmaster-alex-l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281842/child-themed-template-tags-php), I need to override a twentytwenty child theme's `/inc/template.tags`. Based on webmaster-alex-l's thread, I know something needs to be added to my child-theme's `functions.php`, but what?

I tried grabbing some of the php from the parent `/inc/template-tags.php` and putting it into my child-theme's `functions.php` but I don't know what I'm doing, apparently, and I'm getting a critical site error.

Comment: I found a workaround that was easy, so I'm no longer in need of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to hide the 'author' meta info on the site because hackers were finding the usernames and trying to get in. I edited two /child-theme/template-parts/' to comment out 'twentytwenty_the_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'single-top' );' in both. Very simple.